# Same directive with different message - angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have buttons like submit, reject and cancel. If i click on this button a small div with comment shows up and a ok and cancel button will be shown. On click of ok popup with 'are you sure' message popups up.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="showDiv = !showDiv">Submit
</button>
<button type="button" ng-click="showDiv = !showDiv">Reject
</button>
```

I am using a popup modal directive like this for the small div as i mentioned above:

```
<div ng-show="showDiv">
 <yes-no msg="are you sure"></yes-no>
</div>
```

Now I want to change the msg on click of each button. Suppose if i click 'Submit' my msg should be 'are you sure to submit' if i click 'reject' my msg should be 'are you sure to reject'.

directive:

```
mainapp.directive('yesNo', function($modal){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            msg: '@msg'
        },
        link: linkFn
    };

    function linkFn(scope, element, attrs) {
        var msg = attrs.msg;
        var modalTemplate =  '<div class="modal-content">' +
                        '   <div class="modal-body">' +
                        '       <h4 class="modal-title">' + msg + '</h4>' +
                        '   </div>';
           var modalInstance = $modal.open({
               template: modalTemplate,
               controller: 'yesNoModalCtrl'
           });
       });
    }
});
```

How to achieve this? I will not be able to post the code here.

Comment: Add data to your directive `submit-msg` and `reject-msg`

Comment: Why won't you be able to post the code here? At least include some relevant code, otherwise I am not able to post an answer here.

Comment: @Weedoze i would like to display message based on the button click. If i click submit then how can i identify whether i have clicked the submit button?

Comment: @devqon i will try to post some relevant code

Comment: @devqon i have posted the sample code.

Comment: In your directive you gave restrict: 'A', but you are using it as element. Change it to restrict: 'E' or restrict: 'AE',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="button" name="submit" ng-click="buttonclick('are you sure to submit')"/>

<input type="button" name="reject" ng-click="buttonclick('are you sure to reject')"/>

<div ng-show="showDiv">
 <yes-no msg={{message}}></yes-no>
</div>
```

**In you main controller:**

```
app.controller("mainController", function($scope){

$scope.message="";
$scope.buttonclick = function(msg){
   $scope.message= msg;
}
});
app.directive("yesNo", function(){
     return{
     restrict: 'E',
     scope:{
     msg:'@'
    }, 
    link: linkFn,
    controller: 'yesNoModalCtrl'
    }
});
```

In directives Link function

```
function linkFn(scope, element, attrs) {

    attrs.$observe('msg', function(msg) {
        // this function gets triggered each time "msg" is changed
        // You can do whatever you want here
        if (msg) {
            var modalTemplate = '<div class="modal-content">' +
                '   <div class="modal-body">' +
                '       <h4 class="modal-title">' + msg + '</h4>' +
                '   </div>';
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                template: modalTemplate,
                controller: 'yesNoModalCtrl'
            });
        }

    });
}
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VX80jSRwNlERzj84SZjm?p=preview)

Comment: <input type="button" name="submit" ng-click="message='are you sure to submit' " />

<input type="button" name="reject" ng-click="message='are you sure to reject' "/> but i am getting the message as blank in the popup

Comment: Do you have message declared on scope?

Comment: yes. Now i have changed the code as given by you. Even now i am getting the message as blank

Comment: Thanks, It works but i am getting two same popus :( I have tried unbinding the click event but still i am getting two popus.

Comment: my bad i gave the unbinding in the wrong place. It works like a charm thanks a lot Ravi :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a controller function:

```
$scope.showModal = function(msg) {
    $scope.showDiv = !$scope.showDiv;
    $scope.msg = msg;
}
```

And in your buttons:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="showModal('Are you sure')">Submit
</button>
<button type="button" ng-click="showModal('Some other text')">Reject
</button>

<div ng-show="showDiv">
    <yes-no msg="msg"></yes-no>
</div>
```